# Converting char array into NSString object

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring

As per my assignment I have to take in input from a user via a console to be used with `NSString`.

At the moment I have

```
char* name[100]; // declaring char array
NSString* firstName; // declaring the NSString

printf("Please enter first name \n");
printf("=> ");
scanf("%s", &name);

firstName = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This works, however I am getting this warning

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'char *[100]' to parameter of type
>   'const char* '

I don't want to be having these errors coming up in the code, I would like to also mention I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Can anyone explain to me *why* I'm getting these errors, and if I can possibly overcome them?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

Change this:

```
char* name[100];
```

to

```
char name[100];
```

The first form creates an array of 100 *pointers* to `char`. The second one creates an array of 100 `char` elements. What might be confusing, is that `name` in that last case, is in fact a pointer, pointing to the first of these 100 `char` elements.

Answer (score 6):

As printed with NSLog is assigned to initialize a NSString.

```
NSLog(@"%s", arrayChar);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", arrayChar];
NSLog(@"Array to String: %@",str);
```